# Gridview not updating within update panel

Tags: vb.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

Using Visual Studio 2015 (VB) with SQL Server 2012. This is going to be complicated please bear with me.

My questions is why wont my gridview update?

I have a web page that creates txt files in a remote server location.  These files are then picked up by a separate (third party tool) which sends them to a government body.  The government body then sends a receipt file for each txt file which my web app then picks up and records the result.  The result is either an acceptance or a rejection.

On the web page I provide a gridview showing the last ten results and if I send 1 file at a time (with every click of the button) my gridview will refresh without issue showing the results of the receipts.  There can be up to minute gap between the creation of the file, the file sending and the receipt being received.

The image below shows an example of my gridview after successful submission and receipt.

[image: Grid View showing results]

As the button is clicked the sent and accepted column display as red with 'No' within them.

When the button is clicked to send the file a sub is processed that creates the file.  A timer is then enabled (fires every ten seconds) that runs another sub to check for sent and receipts.  I have no issue with this as it works as expected and each cell within the gridview changes to reflect the sent and receipt status.

This is done using a call to build the gridview.

The call

```
    displayLastSentGridView()
    displayHistoryGridView()
    historyUpdatePanel.Update()
```

One of the subs to build the gridview

```
Public Sub displayLastSentGridView()

    Dim mlastSent As New lastSent
    Dim mLastSents As New List(Of lastSent)
    mLastSents = mlastSent.lastSentGridView
    gridLastSent.DataSource = mLastSents
    gridLastSent.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Ok so a request came in that when a particular file is created a further 4 are generated (with a different layout) and auto sent.  I have implemented this and it works as expected.  I then use a new sub to check on the status of these files (as their classification is different).  When the file is sent the web page updates the database flagging the entry as sent, when the receipt is accepted it flags it as accepted.   My problem occurs here.  I use the same code as above to call the gridview updates when the sent even occurs and when the acceptance comes in but the gridviedw does not update.

If I place the code at the end of the sub routine all the cells update i.e. it will update the gridview in one go and all the cells turn green with Yes inside them, but i want it to update each cell as the database notifications are changed.

Below is an excert from my code that checks the folder location `strSentFileLocation` if it exists the database is updated and then the call to update the gridviews is made.  The database update works but the gridview doesnt change.

```
If File.Exists(strSentFileLocation) Then

    db.ngc_updateActivityLogSent(True, seq)
    db.ngc_updateActivityLogRejected(False, "N/A", seq)
    db.ngc_updateActivityLogAccepted(False, seq)

    'update gridviews
    displayLastSentGridView()
    displayHistoryGridView()
    historyUpdatePanel.Update()

End If
```

My update panel is set to conditional.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks

UPDATE

For info the `IF` statement is nested within a `FOR` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The from was the for loops, as the sub never actually finished the update panel never got chance to update till right at the end. I have removed the for loop and added in a hidden field that I increment and call the sub until the hidden field reaches a specific value.